# Can't change table cell width

Tags: html

I have a table that contains another small table in a cell:

```
<table id="big" style='width: 100%'>
 <tr>
  ..
  <td>..</td>
  ..
 </tr>
 <tr>
  ..
  <td style='width: 75px'>
    <table style='width: 100%'>
     <tr>
      <td style='width: 33%'><select></select></td>
      <td style='width: 33%'><select></select></td>
      <td style='width: 33%'><select></select></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  ..
 </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, I have a small table which should take the whole outer cell. This table should be divided into 1x3 cells, each containing a select combo box.

Now the inner table always takes too big width than specified, corrupting the outer table GUI.

As you can see, I have tried to limit the outer cell width in pixels, without any success.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `width:100%` from the inner Table?

Comment: Yes, tried with percent and with absolute pixel values

Comment: The code posted does not match the image shown. It is something in the `select` elements (which are really not empty as in the code posted) or CSS settings that causes the cells to be wider.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to specify [fixed table layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) to respect column width even if content needs more space:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Added it to the inner table only and works perfectly