# I'm trying to put a width to an <td> tag in html in ngFor but is not working

Tags: angular, column-width

```
     <tbody>
               <tr *ngFor="let post of postArray; let i=index">
                            <td width="10"> {{ i + 1 }} </td>
               <td width="200"><img src="{{post.data.postImgPath}}" class="img img-fluid"></td>
                 <td width="200"> {{post.data.title}} </td>
                   <td width="300"> {{post.data.excerpt}} </td>
                       <td>{{post.data.category.category}}</td>
                         <td>{{post.data.createdAt}}</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
          </tbody>
```

I tried with <td [style.width]="300"> {{post.data.excerpt}}

But is not working either.
I tried with:

I tried with <td [style.width.px]="300.px"> {{post.data.excerpt}}

But is not working either.

Can u plaese tell me how to attach width to

Comment: None of the reply's so far is working for me. Any more ideas how to access the td in order to resize the width of the different td rows in my app. I dont know how to get to td in a table. So far 5 hours i'm stacked there and the application is not running correctly. Please help.

Comment: [<td> width not working in my table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587620/cant-change-table-cell-width)

Answer (score 0):

Altough I dont understand *why* you'd want to style the component in the html, heres a way that should work.

```html
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let post of postArray; let i=index">
      <td [style.width]="'10px'"> {{ i + 1 }} </td>
      <td [style.width]="'200px'">
         <img src="{{post.data.postImgPath}}" class="img img-fluid"/>
      </td>
      <td [style.width]="'200px'"> {{post.data.title}} </td>
      <td [style.width]="'300px'"> {{post.data.excerpt}} </td>
      <td>{{post.data.category.category}}</td>
      <td>{{post.data.createdAt}}</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Note that it would be better to style the component over classes and a style file (css).

Comment: Thank you, i tried with css style is not working either and your solution too, i tried it already. I'' try to attach image to see where i want to resize .

Comment: I'm new here and i dont know form where can i attach picture to my question.

Comment: I attached a link so u can see what i'm trying to resize:) but with your code is not working?

Answer (score 0):

width will not work with td, try to add with th tag.

for eg.

```
<table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th [style.width]="'10px'">#</th>
      <th [style.width]="'10px'">Img</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let post of postArray; let i=index">
      <td > {{ i + 1 }} </td>
      <td [style.width]="'200px'">
         <img src="{{post.data.postImgPath}}" class="img img-fluid"/>
      </td>      
   </tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i already have th tag in use and if i change td to th tag app is not working